# Is it better to use jquery than java script?

Tags: jquery

Do you think its better to code in Jquery than Java Script ? Currently I'm learning Jquery and I also have a little knowledge of java script and I'm wondering about above question .

Comment: Learn both, use what suits your need best. If you're going to learn jQuery you should definitely understand JavaScript first though.

Comment: Asking Opinion / Recommendation is strictly Off-Topic here !

Answer (score -1):

yes you can use jquery instead of javascript but it is necessary that you have proper knowledge of javascript.
In jquery there is huge predefined function library for simply implementation
but sometimes you have to use javascript code inside jquery.
Actually jquery is the extended version of javascript.
Good Luck.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked and has misleading details such as "jquery is the extended version of javascript" (jQuery is simply a *Javascript library*).

Answer (score -1):

jQuery is nothing but a library written in javascript. It ease out work of developers as it is rich functional.

But, if there is something that can be easily done in javascript so you should go for javascript not jQuery due to fact JS is native so it increases performence.

Comment: Suggesting using JS, and not using jQuery, for "performance reasons" is *not* good general advice. Performance is very specific to individual tasks. Given that jQuery produces much shorter, [generally] more readable code, the development & maintenance benefits frequently outweigh any performance drop.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thanks!! I totally agree with you!